# Binning based on percentage missing data

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have monthly customer records for a particular period (say from 2000-10 till 2005-03 inclusive). Most customers have one record per month for each of the months in this period. This would be, in total, 54 records for this period.

However, some have some of this data missing.

I would like to produce stats showing how many customers have

- 0%
- less than 1%
- less than 5%
- less than 10%
- more than 10%

missing records for this period. How to do that?

I am including a tiny subset of the data. It shows that customer 2 doesn't have a record for 2001-02.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'cust_id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
                 'period' : [200010,200011,200012,200101,200102,200103,200010,200011,200012,200101,200103],
                 'volume' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12],
                 'num_transactions': [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
period = df.period.unique() # OR pd.period_range('2000-10', '2001-03', freq='M')
df_missing_percent = 1 - df.cust_id.value_counts() / period.size
```

or if you want to account for null values in existing records too:

```py
df_missing_percent = df.pivot(columns='period', index='cust_id').T.isna().mean()
```

then:

```py
sum(df_missing_percent == 0)    # 1
sum(df_missing_percent < 0.01)  # 1
sum(df_missing_percent < 0.05)  # 1
sum(df_missing_percent < 0.10)  # 1
sum(df_missing_percent > 0.10)  # 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I like the elegance of your solution. However, it seems to me that you consider all missing values. For some columns there are missing values. But that's not main problem. The main problem is that for some customers for certain periods no values whatsoever exist (the monthly record for that customer is simply missing).

Comment: @Nick I've revised my answer to account for that as well.

Comment: @Nick also note that the alternative of "hard coding" the period length using `pd.period_range().size` should be preferred, since there's no guarantee that all months appear at least once in the DataFrame. It's possible that a single month would be missing for all customers.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cust_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'period': [200010, 200011, 200012, 200101, 200102, 200103, 200010, 200011, 200012, 200101, 200103],
    'volume': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12],
    'num_transactions': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
})

# I created a DataFrame with all possible combinations of customer IDs and periods
all_cust_ids = df['cust_id'].unique()
all_periods = [y * 100 + m for y in range(2000, 2006) for m in range(1, 13)]
all_periods = [p for p in all_periods if p <= 200503] # I considered only the interval up to March 2005
all_combinations = pd.DataFrame([(cust_id, period) for cust_id in all_cust_ids for period in all_periods], columns=['cust_id', 'period'])

# Then I merged the original df with all possible combinations
merged_df = pd.merge(all_combinations, df, on=['cust_id', 'period'], how='left')

# missing records
merged_df['missing'] = merged_df['volume'].isna()

# I had to grpup by customer and calculate the percentage of missing records
missing_stats = merged_df.groupby('cust_id')['missing'].mean().reset_index()
missing_stats['missing_percentage'] = missing_stats['missing'] * 100

# Then I classified the customers into categories
counts = {
    '0%': len(missing_stats[missing_stats['missing_percentage'] == 0]),
    'less than 1%': len(missing_stats[(missing_stats['missing_percentage'] > 0) & (missing_stats['missing_percentage'] < 1)]),
    'less than 5%': len(missing_stats[(missing_stats['missing_percentage'] >= 1) & (missing_stats['missing_percentage'] < 5)]),
    'less than 10%': len(missing_stats[(missing_stats['missing_percentage'] >= 5) & (missing_stats['missing_percentage'] < 10)]),
    'more than 10%': len(missing_stats[missing_stats['missing_percentage'] >= 10])
}


for category, count in counts.items():
    print(f'{category}: {count} customers')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Amira Bedhiafi got this correct first.

I like the elegance of EliadL's solution.

I would like to split the acceptance between their answers but since I can't I'll pick the solution of EliadL.

Thank you very much to both - I learned from both your answers!

I just want to add a few lines that I needed to add to the solution of EliadL:

```
df_missing_percent = 1 - df.cust_id.value_counts() / df.period.nunique()
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0, 0.05), (0.05, 0.1), (0.1, 1)], closed = 'left')
binned_cust = pd.cut(df_missing_percent, bins)
binned_cust.groupby(binned_cust).count()
```

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I've edited my answer again to provide a better alternative of "hard coding" the period length using `pd.period_range().size`. It should be preferred since there's no guarantee that all months appear at least once in the DataFrame. It's possible that a single month would be missing for all customers.